# Shopify Accessing section.settings with API

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is it possible to access section data with the shopify API?

I want to pull things from section.settings.whatever to build custom storefront functionality. I would prefer not to pass them all as DOM variables in the template.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get all the settings and you don't need to update all the liquid files. I will show you how to do in python you need to do it in your preferred language.

```
settings_schema = shopify.Asset.find('config/settings_schema.json')
#edit the file and the parameters and push it back to shopify

settings_data = shopify.Asset.find('config/settings_data.json')
#edit the file and the parameters and push it back to shopify
```

These 2 files contain all your theme settings and can be found in Config directory of your Shopify Theme.